# Security warning in IE when using jScrollpane

Tags: jquery, https

I am using JSrollpane (a jquery plugin) on my page. use of source file for this plugin causing a security warning in IE- "this webpage contains content that will not be delivered using s secure HTTPS connection,which could compromise the security of entire webpage"

i checked for any media resources with is fetched using http nut it's not there.

my page is https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=/visualforce/session%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faexp.ap1.visual.force.com%252Fapex%252Faexp__test_Offer&un=ashok_bommali%40amex.cms&pw=Infy@789

and source file i am using is http://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/raw/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js

any help on this?

thanks, 
Sushil

Comment: @you are acessig http from https mode.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are linking does not have the `https` protocol. Change it so it does, so it is...

> https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/raw/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js

Alternatively, drop the protocol and let the browser figure it out...

> //github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/raw/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js

Comment: i am not  directly using the http://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/raw/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js 
 
i am saving this file to my own server and than using it with a https:// url .

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly linking to the github version, note your URL is SSL-secured (https) while github's one is not (http). Make sure to use https:// url for all the scripts, since github does support it.

Comment: i am not  directly using the http://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/raw/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js 
 
i am saving this file to my own server and than using it with a https:// url .

Comment: You may want to try and use Fiddler to inspect all the requests if you haven't already. It could something hidden, like an image in a CSS file. Does the issue disappear if you don't include jScrollPane's js file? Also, are you using a blank or about: URL anywhere?

Comment: yes, issue disapears when i don't include jScrollPane's js file.

Answer (score 0):

@alex is right but you can also get URI scheme in JS see link
[JavaScript URI class](http://www.poppa.se/blog/javascript-uri-class/) or from Server Side scriptings likes ASP/JSP

Comment: i am not able to open this url

Comment: blogs are restricted at my organization. do u have any alternative link which is not a blog ,plz give me that.

Comment: hmm please try to use FireFox proxy like FoxyProxy to by pass it may help